# homework: use number of words in one file(through wc) and send it to head as the number of lines

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

Today I had homework in an introductory programming class.

One of the assignments was to take the number of words from one file (using `wc`) and send it to `head` as the number of lines.

This is my code (StackOverflow already helped here):

```
head -n\`wc -w boot.ok\` /var/log/udev > udev.moj
```

After checking:

```
`wc -w boot.ok`
```

it does not equal

```
`wc -l udev.moj`
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `/var/log/udev` has as many lines as `book.ok` has words?

Comment: Yes, it has more lines. Also, the result file udev.moj ends up with slightly more lines than boot.ok has words. At first I though it might have been the blank lines but there aren't enough.

Comment: You are right and I edited. Although, could this not be considered a case of piping as I am sending the output of one command to another?

Comment: No, what you do is command substitution. The commands run one after the other, while with pipes they run in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc -w` doesn't only produce the number of words in the file, it also prints the file name. E.g.:

```
[mureinik@computer tmp]$ echo "hello world" > boot.ok
[mureinik@computer tmp]$ wc -w boot.ok 
2 boot.ok
```

If you feed this into `head -n` as is, `head` will output an error to stderr, and print the entire file. You could use `cut` to extract the numeric part of `wc`:

```
head -n `wc -w boot.ok | cut -f1 -d" "` /var/log/udev > udev.moj
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works correctly after removing the backslashes - which I'm guessing is a formatting error.

Comment: @user3779674 indeed - edited my answer accordingly - thanks for noticing!

Comment: Just FYI, if you send `boot.ok` to `head` on its stdin, rather than telling `head` its name, `head` will be unable to output the filename and you will not need to remove it with `cut`. Try this `wc -w < boot.ok` and then `wc -w boot.ok` and you will see the difference.

Comment: @MarkSetchell nice one! Didn't think of going that way